# What is the computational complexity of Arnoldi algorithm for diagonalization?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, eigenvalues

What is the space and time computational complexity of finding $k$ eigenvalues of an $N\times N$ matrix using the iterative Arnoldi algorithm?

I know that exact diagonalization scales like $O(N^3)$, and I found [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5165662) that using sparse diagonalization one could reduce the complexity to $O(kN^2 + N k^2)$. However, I cannot find a proper reference in the literature for this estimate.

The page on Wikipedia [Eigenvalue algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm) does not provide any information on that. But it doesn't say that it is unknown either.

Comment: the paper you cite explains it quite precisely; isn't that a suitable reference? "The overall computational complexity of an Arnoldi process is $O(kN^2 +k^2N )$ where $k$ is the number of significant eigenvalues. The $O(kN^2)$ cost is due to the computation of $B^{−1}Ax$ at each Arnoldi iteration. The $O(k^2N)$ cost is attributed to the orthonormalization of the $k$ Arnoldi vectors that span the Krylov subspace. In each Arnoldi iteration, the current Arnoldi vector is made orthonormal to all previous Arnoldi vectors."

Comment: I expected to find this information in a numerical mathematics paper rather than an electrical engineering one. Since this is such a common mathematical problem, I am a bit surprised not to find this information easily.